# AWS Glue Zeppelin notebook server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, apache-zeppelin

When you create Glue endpoint and try setting up Zeppelin notebook, there is no setup_notebook_server.py file on location /home/ec2-user. I've done this many times, but first time I see this kind of problem. And yes, IAM role for Zeppelin notebook has all the necessary policies for accessing S3.

Comment: I recently ran into this same problem. I suspect that the documentation is no longer in-sync with reality. I left feedback on the documentation page (and recommend you do the same, so that maybe it gets fixed), then moved on to running a "Glue" environment in Docker per this AWS blog post: [https://awsfeed.com/whats-new/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container]. It worked out quite well, and I was able to upload my scripts to the real Glue environment without issue. Plus, I didn't have to pay for the notebook server or the development endpoint.